# Dynamically create array using formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, datediff, array-formulas

I need to dynamically create an array containing all months between two dates, using `=DATEDIF()` in Google Spreadsheets. For instance, `=DATEDIF(B2,B3,"M")` returns `11`, so I need an array containing all the months between October 2015 and September 2016.

Is it possible to accomplish this using formulas?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXT(EOMONTH(A1,row(OFFSET(A1,,,DATEDIF(A1,A2,"m")))-1),"m"))
```

assuming A1 = date1 (October 2015), A2 = Date2 (September 2016) in date format. `A1` in offset part is the refference on first cell.

change second "m" in formula to get formats:

- "m" = {1,2,3,4...}
- "mm" = {01,02,03...}
- "yyyymm" = {201510, 201511, 201512, 201601...}

[example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z0ktNmr8vn0SC0ByV5bLQ39gy3DXM5FAoIwXHDgcaGk/edit?usp=sharing)